# How to run w32tm in non-elevated powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, ntp

I am writing a helper script that will go through a list of servers and verify they are in sync with the NTP. The script shall be run as a normal script on request by the facility operator and shall request for Admin credentials if the target is not in sync. We unfortunately cannot change the NTP configuration at the moment so we have to make workaround.

What I have right now (and it works beautifully if the script is run as administrator) is a command ("w32tm /query /status" of a remote computer) that is executed via "Invoke-Command" so I can pass it Admin credentials.

My idea was to avoid using WinRM since the hostname resolution is not working properly in our system (it requires some painful host-to-IP-and-back-to-proper-hostname resolution) which makes the WinRM useless.

The command w32tm can obtain status of a remote computer but it needs to be run as administrator for it.

In both cases (run as administrator and run as normal user and later providing the credentials) the $script is executed as domain\administrator (confirmed with the check of Admin role and the "WhoAmI" command) but the status is only obtained when the whole script is executed as administrator. 
For the execution as normal user I receive the error:

```
The following error occurred: Access is denied. (0x80070005)
```

All machines I use obviously allow remote execution since it works with administrator user.

So basically my question is why is the "w32tm ..." command not allowed in the $script if the role of the user is appropriate (it is administrator role) for the task?

The part of the script which I can't resolve:

```
function synchronize_remote_machine ($target, $username, $cred)
{
    $script = { 
        param( [String] $compName )

        $user = [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent();
        $userIsAdmin = (New-Object Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal $user).`
                IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltinRole]::Administrator)  

        if (-not $userIsAdmin)
        {
            Write-Warning "You do not have Administrator rights to run this script!`n
                    Please re-run this script as an Administrator!"
        }
        else    
        {
            whoAmI
            w32tm /query /status /computer:$compName
            #w32tm /resync /rediscover /computer:$compName
        }
    }

    # resync via WinRM
    try 
    {
        #execute_resync_command $target $username $cred
        if ($username -eq 'Administrator')
        {
            # when run as admin
            invoke-command -ScriptBlock $script -ArgumentList $target;
        }
        else
        {
            # for normal user the initalized credential cals is used
            invoke-command -computername "localhost" -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock $script -ArgumentList $target
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        Write-Error "Error executing resync command on host $target."# -foregroundcolor "red"
        throw
    }   
}
```

Comment: I see you checking to see if the current user is an admin, but I don't ever see you checking to see if the credentials passed are administrator creds. Is that handled someplace else?

Comment: I do not check for the password. I've never thought of it because I assumed that since I'm running as the expected user the complete credentials are correct. I assume that because this user (administrator) could not be logged in without them.

Comment: You misunderstood my comment. I see that you function accepts $cred, and uses that variable in `invoke-command -computername "localhost" -Credential $cred` but I don't see where you check those credentials to see if they are an administrator.

Comment: Yes, I did misunderstand your question. What I've found out is that my credentials are really not the Admin credentials I need to run the commands I wish. Why is that I don't know (yet). If I run the `whois /all` the SID of the user is the same as in "run as admin" powershell but the privileges are different.

Comment: Sorry, for the command I meant `whoAmI /all`.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than (re-)running the script with elevated privileges, I'd grant the operators group the `SeSystemtimePrivilege` on those servers. You can do that either with a group policy or by running `ntrights.exe` from the [Server 2003 Resource Kit Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17657) on each server:

```
ntrights +r SeSystemtimePrivilege -u DOMAIN\operators
```

Comment: This is a good suggestion which I have provide to our IT guy but right now we are not able (allowed) to make any changes to the environment (due to the regulatory issues). Unfortunately I'll need a way around this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you execute it as administrator, do to try to run you script in an elevated process ?

You can acheive that using `Start-Process` CmdLet.

```
start-process 'c:\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe' -verb runas -argumentlist "-file YourScript.ps1"
```

Comment: I've followed your suggestion but I get to the same blocking issue I have where the command is not allowed. From what I can tell it seems the credentials provided to the `$script` are not correct and do not give me the correct privileges. Because of this the powershell is not executed with correct privileges and the w32tm command fails.